# client-initiated transactions that closed without COMMIT postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, transactions, pg

I'm using **pg** in **nodejs**, my question is very basic but I can't find official documentation about it, what happens with a transaction that was started by a client that ended its connection without issuing COMMIT?

When there are transactions without confirmation, they simply do ROLLBACK when closing the connection of the client that gave BEGIN?

Comment: Without commit, the data can’t be committed and thus will never be visible to anybody. That is comparable with a rollback. The only difference is that rollback is a statement sent by the client.

Comment: I have doubts about what happens with the memory that maintains that transaction, I suspect that postgresql will have a garbage collector for those situations.

Comment: Autovacuum will take care of the dead tuples, the tuples that were not committed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually find it documented nowhere, but if the connection is terminated before you commit, the transaction is automatically rolled back.  That's a basic requirement for a relational database.

Comment: Apparently there is nothing written in any documentation, I guess that as you mention it is something basic in relational database transactions. Thanks!